# GroupBy Query Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm having problem in fetching the data using groupBy, I don't where I'm wrong, I have done it many times before, but today I'm wrong some where and I don't know where. Following is the Table from which I want to select the Data:

Table Name: **user_questions**

```
id | user_id | message | read_status_user | read_status_support | answered
```

Now suppose if one user sends more than one messages, then user_id will be repeated, So to want all the message from one particular user I'm firing the query like following:

```
UserQuestion::groupBy('user_id')->get();
```

This should give me the result like

```
user_id = 1 > message1
user_id = 1 > message2
....
user_id = 1 > message...(if any)

user_id = 2 > message1
user_id = 2 > message2
..... 
So on...
```

But this is always giving me only one message from the particular user. I don't know why. Is there any mistake? I have tried another queries too, but all are giving me the same result.

Please help me with this. Everybody's help will be highly appreciated. Thanks to all of you in advance.

Comment: post your complete query

Comment: Hi bro I've already written query in the question, but will post it again for you UserQuestion::groupBy('user_id')->get(); (UserQuestion is the Model)

Comment: want complete code. not just part of it

Comment: Hi bro that is only the complete Code in the Method I have written :)

Comment: public function getAdminChat()
    {
        $userReplies = UserQuestion::groupBy('user_id')->get();
        dd($userReplies);
    }

Comment: Of course it will show one message per user, because you put groupBy user_id. Try to remove the `groupBy('user_id')`. So your code will be `UserQuestion::get();`

Comment: Hi but there would be lots of users who are sending more than one messages

Comment: So you want to get all messages from a particular user right? So you know the user_id of the user. Why don't you try this `UserQuestion::find($user_id);`

Comment: Can you also provide indexes or schema of user_questions tables ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are calling the `groupBy` function of the query builder object, which is what generates the query for your database. When you call the `->get()` method, the query is executed and a `Collection` object containing the results is returned. What you are looking to use is the `groupBy` method of Laravel's `Collection` class, which means you need to put the `->groupBy('user_id')` after the `->get()`.

Assuming you have the following data:

```
user_question
user_id     question_id
1           1
1           2
1           3
2           4
3           5
3           6
```

Your current code

```
UserQuestion::groupBy('user_id')->get();
```

executes this query

```
select * from user_question group by user_id;
```

returning one row per user, since that's what `group by` does in MySQL.

```
user_id     question_id
1           1
2           4
3           5
```

If instead, you do the following

```
$collection = UserQuestion::get();
```

the query is simply

```
select * from user_question
```

and when you call `$collection->groupBy('user_id')` on this collection, you get data structured like

```
[
     1 => [
         [ 'user_id' => 1, 'question_id' => 1 ],
         [ 'user_id' => 1, 'question_id' => 2 ],
         [ 'user_id' => 1, 'question_id' => 3 ]
      ],
      2 => [
          [ 'user_id' => 2, 'question_id' => 4 ],
      ],
      3 => [
          [ 'user_id' => 3, 'question_id' => 5 ],
          [ 'user_id' => 3, 'question_id' => 6 ]
      ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$users = DB::table('table_name')
        ->groupBy('user_id')
        ->get();
```

after that push that to foreach loop

```
foreach ($users as $user)
{
    var_dump($user->name);
}
```

[ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

Comment: I have tried this query too, but this query is not giving me all the messages of one user, it is giving me only the first message of one user

Comment: is there any unique thing to add in where clauese table??

Comment: No there is no such thing to add in where clause right now

Comment: @Siddharth check now

Comment: Okay will try out this thing

Comment: Hi friend, it is still the same, it is giving me only the first message from first user and first message from 2nd user. I want all the messages from first user and all the messages from 2nd user and so on

Comment: `dump($users)` and check array

Comment: still same  getting only one message from first user in that array

Comment: it doesn't work. I don't know why it isn't working. It must work, but thank you so much for your kind replies to me and for helping me bro :)

Answer (score 0):

You've probably found the solution to your problem by now but otherwise, I would suggest to use the relationships. In the User model, I would do:

```
public function questions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserQuestion');
}
```

Then I would get all the users and loop through them to get their messages.

```
$users = User::all();
$users->each(function ($user) {
    $questions = User::find($user->id)->questions;
});
```